# Find K largest elements in a list

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I am trying to implement an algorithm based on the result of `QuickSelect` in which, given the K-th largest element found with `QuickSelect` I want to get the **K largest elements**

This is the implementation of `QuickSelect`:

```
def partition(A, left, right): 
    pivotindex = random.randint(left, right) 
    pivot = A[pivotindex] # get random pivot
    i = left - 1
    for j in range(left, right): 
        if A[j] < pivot:
            i += 1 
            A[i], A[j] = A[j], A[i]
    A[i+1], A[right] = A[right], A[i+1] 
    return i + 1

def QuickSelect(A, K, left, right):
    if left == right:
        return A[left]
    q = partition(A, left, right) 
    i = q - left + 1
    if K == i:
        return A[q]  # this is the element you want to return
    if K < i:
        return QuickSelect(A, K, left, q - 1)
    else:
        return QuickSelect(A, K - i, q + 1, right)

def k_largest(A, K):
    q = QuickSelect(A = A, K = K, left = 0, right = len(a)-1)
    B = [i for i in A if i >= q]
    return B
```

So, what I want to get with the function `k_largest_(A, K)` is a new array **B** in which are present the **K largest elements** up to the K-th element.

By implementing on a random array, I expect that re result is the same as with the function `sorted(a)[-10:]`:

```
a = get_random_array(100, 100)

print(sorted(a)[-10:]) # largest 10 elements, I expect the same result of that array
print(sorted(k_largest(a, 10)))
```

results:

```
[91, 91, 92, 94, 95, 95, 98, 98, 99, 99]
[91, 91, 91, 92, 94, 95, 95, 98, 98, 99, 99]
```

BUT, sometimes I get the same results and sometimes no. Like, in the next try the result is the correct

```
a = get_random_array(100, 100)

print(sorted(a)[-10:]) # largest 10 elements, I expect the same result of that array
print(sorted(k_largest(a, 10)))

[92, 93, 94, 95, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 99]
[92, 93, 94, 95, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 99]
```

What can be the reason I do get sometimes the right result and sometimes no? In which of the three function can be the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be on the last method, `k_largest`.
More precisely the line

`B = [i for i in A if i >= q]`

where, if I understood correctly, `q` is the value of the 10-th (or k-th) largest number. The problem here is that if there are several values which has the same value as `q`, they will all be included.

So, depending on the random generation, if there are many 10-th (or k-th) largest values, they will all be included.

**How to correct it?**

Picking the last 10 elements of B would not guarantee it, because they may not be ordered. Sorting and then doing this would work, but it may be against your idea (I mean, it would work on the whole array then, but maybe on a smaller one is faster).
So maybe you could check the length of B, and while the length is larger than 10, pop out the smallest value.

I am unsure whether this is the optimal method, but I guess the error could lie on that part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think that problem is in this line  `B = [i for i in A if i >= q]`.
Let's say that your last 12 elements are 99. This would return [99, 99, ..., 99] (12 elements). You are missing here your condition that you want to return max K elements. Sometimes the result is correct when the eleventh element is less than a tenth, and sometimes it is wrong when elevent is equal to tenth.